# How to Save OneToMany relationship with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm new to Laravel stack and currently developing an API with Lumen and Eloquent. I have a requirement to save `Order` model together with it's `OrderLine`s. However, it does not go through. Can you please show me how to do that.

Following is my Model and controller setup:

```
class Order extends Model {
    public function orderLines() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLine')
    }
}

class OrderLine extends Model {
    .....
}

//inside OrdersController method I'm trying to save Order with Order lines received from JSON body

public function create(Request $request)
{
    $orderData = $this->validate($request, [
        'store' => 'required',
         ......
        'order_status' => 'bail|required|max:20',
        'delivery_date' => 'nullable|date',
        'customer_id' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'order_lines.*.product_id' => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'order_lines.*.description' => 'bail|required|max:80',
        'order_lines.*.unit_price' => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'order_lines.*.discount' => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'order_lines.*']);


    $order = new Order($orderData);

    $order->push(); // This does not save and gives me an error
    $order->refresh();
    return response()->json($order);

} 

//This is the json body provided in the request
{
    "store" : "Some Store",
    ...
    "order_lines" : [{
                "product_id": 1,
                "description": "TU001: Polka dots",
                "unit_price": 1000,
                "discount": 100,
                "units": 2
    },
    {
                "product_id": 2,
                "description": "TU002: Polka dots",
                "unit_price": 500,
                "discount": 0,
                "units": 1
    }]
}
```

When I try to save Order alone without Order lines using `save` method, it works. But with `OrderLine`s it fails.

Can somebody please show me how to do this. I used to do this in CakePHP, but not sure how it is done in Eloquent.

//EDIT WITH FURTHER INFO
In the generated insert sql query i see `orderLines` taken as a column in the `Order` table. Since that it gives a Array to String conversion error. But actually insertion of `orderLines` should be in a separate sql query.

Comment: ‘$order = Order::find(1); $order->orderLine()->create($data);’ - have you tried something like that? I  not sure if it is possible to what you after with a single line.

Comment: @user3402600 yes it did't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'store' => 'required',
         ......
        'order_status' => 'bail|required|max:20',
        'delivery_date' => 'nullable|date',
        'customer_id' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'order_lines.*.product_id' => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'order_lines.*.description' => 'bail|required|max:80',
        'order_lines.*.unit_price' => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'order_lines.*.discount' => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'order_lines.*'
    ]);

    $order = new Order($request->except('order_lines'));
    $order->save();

    $order->orderLines()->createMany($request->input('order_lines'));

    $order->load('order_lines'); //not sure that you need this line

    return $order;
}
```

Comment: "Form requests are not supported by Lumen. If you would like to use form requests, you should use the full Laravel framework."[link](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

Comment: No problem, you can use validate method instead of request class.

Comment: Yes Eloquent is incapable of persisting related models in one go unlike CakePHP or JPA. I had to call several `save` methods inside a transaction to get the desired result.